# Google maps - get static map link

Tags: google-maps, web-applications, jquery-gmap3

I have web application that generates a dynamic map with a rout beetween N waypoins, origin and destination using gmap3 jquery plugin. Now I need to add a function to genereate a pdf with that map server-side. I need to send to the server the link to the static map rappresenting my dynamic generated map in order of re-generate the image rappresenting the map and put it into a file.
There is a way to obtain the link to the static map maybe using gmap3?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  There is the Static Maps API, which you can pass a URL to representing a place with markers, polygons etc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: thank you for your interest. I need to generate the static map link from the dynamic map programmaticaly

Comment: Ok, it'll help if we can see your existing code that generates that dynamic map.